# Sharing properties among multiple C# Classes

Tags: c#, .net, composition

I'm trying to maximize my code reuse here.  I have a `SearchQueryDto` with fields like the below:

```
public class SearchQueryDto{
    // some other properties 
    public string SearchUsername { get; set; }         // repetition 1
    public string SearchProfile { get; set; }          // repetition 1
    public SearchInterest SearchInterest { get; set; } // repetition 1
    // some other properties 
}
```

Then, I have a database model for `Broadcast` with the following:

```
public class Broadcast {
    // some other different properties 
    public string SearchUsername { get; set; }          // repetition 1     
    public string SearchProfile { get; set; }           // repetition 1
    public SearchInterest SearchInterest { get; set; }  // repetition 1
    // some other different properties 
    public Status Status {get; set;}                    // repetition 2
    public DateTime DateStarted {get; set;}             // repetition 2
}
```

Then, I have a database model for `BroadcastMessage` with the following:

```
public class BroadcastMessage {
    // some other properties 
    public Status Status {get; set;}                    // repetition 2
    public DateTime DateStarted {get; set;}             // repetition 2
}
```

As it stands, adding new search criteria means I have to go and add fields to both my database model `Broadcast` AND the DTO.  How can I share properties between two classes?  Inheritance doesn't seem to be the answer because I might end up sharing properties between `Broadcast` and some other type as well.

I'm looking for something simple, like:

```
// handles repetition 1
public class SearchCriteria{
    public string SearchUsername { get; set; }
    public string SearchProfile { get; set; }
    public SearchInterest SearchInterest { get; set; }
}
// handles repetition 2
public class StatusProperties{
    public Status Status {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateStarted {get; set;}
}

public class SearchQueryDto: SearchCriteria{               
    // some other properties 
}
public class Broadcast : SearchCriteria, StatusProperties{ // multiple inheritance :(
    // some other different properties 
}
public class BroadcastMessage : StatusProperties{
    // some other properties 
}
```

I don't think inheritance will work because of `Broadcast` needs, and I don't think interfaces will work because then I've taken a step in the wrong direction - updating `n+1` things instead of just `n` things for the convenience of compiler enforcing the inheritance (not the convenience I'm looking for).

I also don't want to hide these properties behind an instantiation of another class for reasons that I think are out-of-scope here.

Comment: Maybe a solution is to create an intermediate class which will hold the common properties you want to share, then both your classes have a reference to that class...

Comment: @SuperPeanut - I like that... but how do I go about the referencing bit without embedding those objects behind another property?

Comment: How about making a new (maybe abstract) type above the 2 making the 2 inherit this new type. Also, why not just use 1 type seeing the 2 have the same properties. If you ever happen to have to add new properties that one of the 2 uses does not need, then you just need to inherit a new type from this one.

Comment: What you are describing is the primary goal of a DTO: by limitating its properties and chosing only the ones you actually wanna send, you avoid some problems that could occur, like serializing by mistake a lazy relationship (in case you use an automapper to copy the data from one object to another, for example).

Comment: @FrancisLord - updated question to try and explain why I think inheritance won't work.  Thoughts?

Comment: @JonathanHiben I think my usage of DTOs is out-of-scope here - pretend it's a normal class :p

Comment: I've only ever seen this result in overly complex code that becomes hard to change. The purposes for these objects are not the same, so they don't need to draw from a single implementation. I don't deem this a problem worth solving. Think code generation if you think its laborious to write out

Comment: @Biscuits That's where the subjective nature of programming comes into play I suppose.  I have a need and am wondering if this tool has the constructs to address it - I don't think philosophy belongs here.

Comment: Please don't interpret my philosophy for an answer. Just adding something to ponder.

Comment: I've used multiple partial classes before that I've selectively linked into projects to extend their implementations, but this might not provide all the control you need and soon only becomes silly to try and maintain.

Comment: @Biscuits right on.  My overall goal here is subjective by nature which makes this tough - I'm going for elegance and simplicity.  If I ever have to update / rearchitect `SearchCriteria` or `StatusProperties` - their dependencies will want those updates as well (and I want to make sure they get them).  What I don't want is a ton of overhead around repeated definitions and high potential for inconsistency or human error there from devs that don't know these constructs are shared.  Interfaces solve some of that... but not all of it.

Comment: In my opinion you're not repeating a definition when the object serves purposes decided by the design in another part of the application. You would otherwise violate the single responsibility principle. Don't let these designs pollute or constrain one another - the one might as well be fully concealed behind the other, if API compatibility becomes important.

Comment: @Biscuits - does SRP apply to both classes and properties?  The properties are serving the same exact purpose between classes, so it does feel right to DRY them up.  Maybe SRP and DRY are butting heads here, or I've misunderstood one or both.

Comment: I guess that's why they're mere principles. But the goal of DRY is to make for code that's simple to maintain and engineering meaningless abstractions defies that. What you're trying to do is draw from single implementations that become hard to name or describe. Are you maybe over-thinking it? Again, think code generation for productivity and to avoid mistakes.

Comment: @Biscuits - probably.  I'm a stubborn purist.  What would you do here?  Single inheritance and repeated `Status` properties?  Or purely separate classes with repeated properties across the board?  FYI `SearchCriteria` has around 30 properties :(

Comment: I would keep them entirely separated, typing every class and property as a duplicate in the shortest, most eloquent way possible and write unit tests to make assertions about design consistencies.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a huge fan of using a shared container class or inheritance because this brings the model, DTO objects, ViewModels and other separated classes too much together in my opinion.
I think it's the best solution to implement the properties in each class.

---

But I think it would be no problem to use an interface to avoid a forgotten property.

```
public interface IBroadcastMessage{
    public Status Status {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateStarted {get; set;}
}

public class Broadcast : IBroadcastMessage, ISearchQueryDto { /* ... */ }
public class BroadcastMessage : IBroadcastMessage { /* ... */ }
```

This does not help to avoid similar code, quite the opposite you must write all you're properties once more. But if you implement it in the interface you cannot forget to implement it in all classes.
Interfaces like these can be helpful on other places too. e.g. for passing an `IBroadcastMessage` and don't care which exact type it is.

---

In this case, what about a refactoring? Why adding a property for each new criteria if you can create a base class which can filter items depending on inherited implementations and add them to a list? Just an idea.

Comment: As stated in my question, neither inheritance nor interfaces solve my particular problem.  I'm fully aware of the benefits they provide, but those aren't the benefits I'm looking for.

Comment: @RobVious I wrote that answer primarily because of the third line of my first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object that both classes have instances of.  An update to the SearchCriteria updates the properties in both of those classes.  Your two classes (broadcast and profilesearchdto) remain decoupled.

```
SearchCriteria{
    public string SearchUsername { get; set; }
    public string SearchProfile { get; set; }
    public SearchInterest SearchInterest { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileSearchDto {
    public SearchCriteria searchCriteria {get; set;}
}

public class Broadcast {
    public SearchCriteria searchCriteria {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I was about to post just that. That's the only way I can see it without inheritance.

Comment: I'm really trying to avoid hiding these properties behind another property.

Comment: Then use an interface.

Comment: @wizardzz as stated in my question, interfaces don't solve my problem.

Comment: @RobVious its seems those are really your only options. Repeat, Inherit, Interface, Compose(and hide).

Comment: @RobVious, I'm trying to see why interfaces do not solve your problem. What is the additional updating if you use interface. The interface and underlying class? but not all the classes that use the interface, and the interface will help keep changes to the properties from breaking because you will not be accessing the properties directly. it's really 1 vs 2, not n vs n+1

Comment: @hometoast I agree.

Comment: @RobVious, I provided an answer as the question was stated at the time. Edits were made to the OP after my answer to exclude it.

Comment: @wizardzz - yes you're right - I apologize for not giving a clear picture from the beginning.